# Django: How do I handle urls with multiple apps

Tags: python, django

I have two apps: `core` and `dm`
Here's my code:

core/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index')
]
```

dm/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.dm, name='dm'),
    path('prices', views.dm_prices, name='prices')
]
```

mysite/urls.py

```
from core import views
from dm import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('core.urls')),
    path("stripe/", include("djstripe.urls", namespace="djstripe")),
    path('dm', include('dm.urls')),
    path('dm/prices', include('dm.urls')),
]
```

And so, looking from the 404 page, I can see that the URLs he sees are:

1. admin/
2. [name='index']
3. stripe/
4. dm [name='dm']
5. dm prices [name='prices']
6. dm/prices [name='dm']
7. dm/prices prices [name='prices']

I would be really happy if someone could explain to me how django reads the different URLs and how it orders them.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: what url are you trying to access that raised 404?

Comment: @mangoorange just a random one, so I could show what urls I get

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to include urls of same app twice, `include('<my_app>.urls')` will include all the urls you mentioned in your app's `urlpatterns`. So `'dm/prices'` is redundant in your case, and changing it to this will do the job.

```
from core import views
from dm import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('core.urls')),
    path('dm/', include('dm.urls')),
    path("stripe/", include("djstripe.urls", namespace="djstripe")),
]
```

For more information about `include()` read this [`django docs`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs)

Comment: Yes it worked. So in the mysite/urls.py I just need to include an app once, and the route that I gave it will go to the beginning of all URLs of the app, right?

Answer (score 3):

It's maybe a bit outside of the scope of your question, but is the 404 page the problem you would like to solve?

As Rustam Garayev said `path('dm', include('dm.urls'))`, django includes all urls from that file (the same applies to those in the `'core'` path). That's why they appear twice. You essentially created four paths:

- `<yoursite>/dm/` (namespace `dm`)
- `<yoursite>/dm/prices` (namespace `prices`)
- `<yoursite>/dm/prices` (namespace `dm`)
- `<yoursite>/dm/prices/prices` (namespace `prices`)

The ordering is the same as in the file that imports the apps' urls, i. e. 1 and 2 are the result from your first `include` statement, 3 and 4 from the second.

By the way, I realized that you're importing two `views` functions (`core.views` and `dm.views`) and recommend to define an alias in order to avoid name clashes in case you have methods with the same name in them.

```py
from core import views as cviews
from dm import views as dviews
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. No, the 404 page was just so I could see the list of URLs Django generated/saw. Btw thanks for the alias recommendation, I'll do just like you said.